# How to get 'deleted by us' file back from master?

Tags: git

I am updating my branch from master and have a merge error:

```
#       deleted by us:    scss/styles.scss
```

However, I want to keep this file.

I've tried:

```
git checkout --theirs scss/styles.scss
```

but this does nothing (no error, no file changes).

Would anyone know the correct way of going about bringing this file back into my branch?

Comment: That leading slash on the path name seems wrong: it should not be `/scss/something`, but `scss/something` would make sense. Given that this is pasted Git output, though, that makes it even odder.

Comment: @torek yeah I just typed it in. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `styles.css` exist in origin/master.

```
$ git checkout origin/master scss/styles.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -- /path/to/file
```

To restore it to the latest commit in your current branch

```
git checkout HEAD -- /path/to/file
```